# Angular get value from NgModel

Tags: php, angular, ionic-framework

I want to send multiple values from a  to an API function.

on the DB I store the values in text format. The value that is stored is **array**

on the Swal alert, I am getting [object object] but I want to get each value e.g. Painting or Graphic Design.

Here is my code so far.

HTML

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Painting</ion-label>
  <ion-toggle color="gold" [(ngModel)]="creative.Painting" (click)="creativeInterest(creative)"></ion-toggle>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Graphic Design</ion-label>
  <ion-toggle color="tertiary" [(ngModel)]="creative.Graphic Design" (click)="creativeInterest(creative)"></ion-toggle>
</ion-item>
```

.ts

```
export class CreativeSettingsPage implements OnInit {
    creative: any = {};
    userDetails: any = {};
    constructor(
      public userData: UserData
  ) {
    this.userDetails = this.userData.getUserData();
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  creativeInterest(creative:string)
  {
    this.userData.creativeSettings(this.userDetails.uid, creative).pipe(
      map((data: any) => {
        if (data.success) {
          Swal.fire({
            icon: 'success',
            title: creative,
            showConfirmButton: false,
            backdrop: false,
            timer: 2500
          })
        }
      })
    ).subscribe()
  }
```

user-data.ts

```
creativeSettings(uid: number, creative:any) {
        const url = this.appData.getApiUrl() + 'creativeSettings';
        const data = this.jsonToURLEncoded({
            uid: uid,
            creative: creative
        });
        return this.http.post(url, data, { headers: this.options });
    }
```

PHP

```
function creativeSettings()
{
    
    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $response['success'] = true; // 1 true if not errors OK NOTHING

    $uid = $request->post('uid');
    $creative_interests =  $request->post('creative');

    $db = getDB();
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET creative_interests = :creative_interests WHERE uid = :uid";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam("uid", $uid);
    $stmt->bindParam("creative_interests", $creative_interests);
    $stmt->execute();
    $db = null;

    echo json_encode($response);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, when naming object properties in JS, the usual naming convention is camelCase. For example:

`creative.Painting` should become `creative.painting`

`creative.Graphic Design` should become `creative.graphicDesign`

Secondly, you are passing the whole `creative` object to Swal and it expects a string, that is why you get `[object Object]`. It can't automatically assume which property to display, you need to explicitly state that. One solution would be to pass the title you would like to display as an argument of the `creativeInterest(creative:string)` method, i.e:

```js
  creativeInterest(creative:string, messageTitle: string)
  {
    this.userData.creativeSettings(this.userDetails.uid, creative).pipe(
      map((data: any) => {
        if (data.success) {
          Swal.fire({
            icon: 'success',
            title: messageTitle,
            showConfirmButton: false,
            backdrop: false,
            timer: 2500
          })
        }
      })
    ).subscribe()
  }
```

and in you component markup (unchanged parts omitted from the snippet below):

```html
<ion-toggle color="gold" [(ngModel)]="creative.painting" (click)="creativeInterest(creative, 'Painting')"></ion-toggle>

 <ion-toggle color="tertiary" [(ngModel)]="creative.graphicDesign" (click)="creativeInterest(creative, 'Graphic Design')"></ion-toggle>
```

Comment: Thanks, ardentia!!! That's a great answer.